# PostgreSql initdb happend exception 0xC000001D on windows server 2003

Tags: postgresql

My server is Windows Server 2003 sp2 x64 Edition.

I use the command at path %PG_HOME%/bin

```
initdb.exe -D d:\pg\data -E UTF8 --locale=C
```

But happend an exception like this:
[initializing dependencies ... child process was terminated by exception 0xC000001D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsId6.png)

When I reinstall windows, it still happend. 
Please help me.

Comment: Do you have an anti-virus installed? If yes de-activate it, or at least add the data directory to the exception list. And which Postgres version are you trying to install?

Comment: Is it possible that this command is not allowed to be run with admin privileges?